# "SDK tools directory is missing" when launching Android Studio on my mac

Tags: android, sdk

[image]

It shows that I've already installed the Android SDK but I can't find it.:<
Tried in terminal to see what's in the folder but find nothing, this location is empty. Why the app tell me that I've installed it? How can I solve this problem? Thank you!!

Comment: A couple of things to check - 1. Sometimes this caused by insufficient space on your hard disk. Did you check this? If so I would mention it in your question. 2. Open Android studio goto Android Studio > Preference and Search for sdk - you can see the location of the SDK there, most of the time it is /Users/<name>/Library/Android/sdk.

Comment: I'm sure that there's approximately 400GB space left on my hard disk. I can only manually download a sdk package and put it in ./Library/Android/sdk. Still I don't know why the app noted that I've installed some sdk before I download one:< Thank you anyway=D

Comment: did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that you reinstall Android Studio after checking the SDK Manager at first. The SDK Path may also be corrupted, so check that.

Comment: Thx, I reinstalled the app and then download a sdk package from other websites and it can find the sdk that I've put in the path. Still I need to use mirrors to download the other packages that's needed, the internet condition's terrible so I decided to copy the whole file from my friend's computer.

Comment: Restarting android studio did it for me

Answer (score 2):

For me it was two issues, proxy settings although tested okay was not connecting to display the list of available SDKs. Also launching Android Studio using "Run as administrator" was also required.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and I came across this post but then before implementing the suggested solutions, I decided to first restart my AndroidStudio, on restart it gave me the option to download SDK and after that, it worked perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by downloading the Android SDK from IntelliJ rather than Android Studio.

Then restart Android Studio, It detects the installed version.